# How to execute RMI on linux

Tags: jmeter, rmi

```
Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jmeter.engine.JMeterEngineException: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.143.3.49; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
2013/03/19 06:15:28 ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 46.137.221.11; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out 
2013/03/19 06:15:28 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jmeter.engine.JMeterEngineException: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 46.137.221.11; nested exception is:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

This is a network connectivity problem, not an RMI or Java problem. Can you ping that host from that client?

Comment: thank you, telnet [ip] 1099 is ok. but still prompt up the problem. the master ip: 10.144.84.123    and the other ip: 10.143.3.49

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'prompt up the problem', but it's still a network connectivity problem.